# Getting UID of the file uploader

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

In the first part of my app users can upload files to "general" view where they are listed. I assign each fileName and URL to specific user. Then i can sort through users and get all fileNames.

I have also implemented uploading files to different folders in my database. By different folders i mean that in table view there are "files" and "folders". It works well. With this feature i am not assigning fileName and Url to specific user. Files go directly to specific folder in database(I don't want my "general" view to show them).

However, the delete function is needed. Is there any way of getting out something like UID of user who uploaded file (or anything else which i can use to link user to it)? I read in firebase documentation that i can create custom metadata, but i am beginner and i have no clue about it (Also, I can't find any examples of custom metadata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are uploading a file, or after you've uploaded a file, you can create a `StorageMetadata` object to specify all the usual metadata you'd expect, such as contentType and encoding, etc.  They also give you an item called `customMetadata` that is a dictionary with whatever you want in it.  So if you wanted to add a userUID in there you could do so like this:

```
let myMetadata = StorageMetadata()
myMetadata.customMetadata = ["userUID" : "abc123"]
```

Once you have this metadata object you can use your storage reference to update the metadata on your file.

```
let fileReference = storageReference.child("files/userImage.jpg")

fileReference.updateMetadata(metadata) { (metadata, error) in
  //Check to see if you need to handle an error, etc.
}
```

You can also do this at the time that you're uploading the file:

```
let fileReference = storageReference.child("files/userThumnail.jpg")

fileReference.putData(imageData, metadata: myMetadata) { (metadata, error) in
  //Handle error, etc.
}
```

Later on, if you need to know the userUID attached to the metadata of a file, you can access it like so:

```
let fileReference = storageReference.child("files/userImage.jpg")

fileReference.getMetadata { (metadata, error) in
  if let data = metadata, let userUID = data.customMetadata["userUID"] as? String {
    //Got it.  Do whatever you need with it.
    print(userUID)
  }
}
```

Comment: I belive that's what I need! I will try to implement it. Thank you so much for your guidance.

Comment: One more question. Is there a way to access metadata for a given URL?

Comment: Sure.  You can get a reference to the file with `let fileReference = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "your_url")`.  Then it's the same as before with `fileReference.getMetadata...`